# LaTeX pgfgantt move inline label above the bar not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, pgfgantt

I'm trying to move my already inline labels to above the bar and have attempted to add `bar inline label node /.style=north` or `bar inline label anchor=north` or `bar inline label anchor/.styles = north` to the options as specified in other questions. None of these give the desired effect. 
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                       Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}                       %Diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{calc, automata}         %Diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, patterns}%Diagrams
\tikzset{>=latex'}                      %Arrow head style

\usepackage{pgfplots}                   %Diagrams
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}                   %Gantt Charts

\usepackage{lscape}                     %allow certain pages to be formatted in landscape orientation
\usepackage[paper=A4,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{afterpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                   Gantt Chart Styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{newbarblue}{RGB}{0,153,255}

\definecolor{newYLyellow}{RGB}{234,187,0}

\definecolor{RoyalBlue}{RGB}{0,35,102}

\def\pgfcalendarweekdayletter#1{%
    \ifcase#1M\or T\or W\or T\or F\or S\or S\fi%
}

\newganttchartelement{newbar}{
                            newbar/.style={
                                shape=rounded rectangle,
                                inner sep=0pt,
                                draw=newbarblue!50!black,
                                very thick,
                                top color=white,
                                bar inline label node /.style=north, %Line which I thought would work
                                bottom color=newbarblue!50
                                },                              
                            newbar label font=\slshape,
                            newbar left shift=-.1,
                            newbar right shift=.1
                         }

\newganttchartelement{newYL}{newYL/.style=  {
                                            shape=rounded rectangle,
                                            inner sep=0pt,
                                            draw=newbarblue!50!black,
                                            very thick,
                                            top color=white,
                                            bar inline label node /.style=north,  %Line which I thought would work
                                            bottom color=newYLyellow!50
                                        },
                            newbar label font=\slshape,
                            newbar left shift=-.1,
                            newbar right shift=.1
                        }

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{weekendstripes}{\pgfpoint{-1mm}{-1mm}}{\pgfpoint{40mm}{11mm}}{\pgfpoint{19.80mm}{10mm}}%
{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{3.4cm}{0cm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.4cm}{1cm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.0cm}{1cm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.0cm}{0cm}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.4cm}{0cm}}
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                   Start of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


\afterpage{% Insert after the current page
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{
         top = 1in, left = 1.5in, right = 1in, bottom = 1in}

\resizebox{2.4\hsize}{!}{   
\begin{ganttchart}[canvas/.style=%
                {pattern=weekendstripes, pattern color=gray!20},
                x unit= 4mm,
                vgrid={*{6}{dotted},*{1}{black}},
                hgrid,
                inline,
                time slot format=little-endian,
                group/.append style={draw=black, fill=RoyalBlue!70},
                milestone/.append style={draw=black, fill=RoyalBlue!70},
                milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm}            
              ] {12-01-2015}{14-05-2015}

\gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=RoyalBlue},
                title left shift=.1,
                title right shift=-.1,
                title label font=\color{white}\bfseries]        {month=shortname}\\

\gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=RoyalBlue!80},
                title left shift=.1,
                title right shift=-.1,
                title label font=\color{white}\bfseries]        {week=1}\\

\gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=RoyalBlue!60},
                title left shift=.05,
                title right shift=-.05,
                title label font=\color{white}\bfseries
               ]                                                {weekday=letter}\\


\ganttgroup{Group1}                             {16-02-2015}{06-03-2015} \\ 

\ganttnewbar{Task1}                             {12-01-2015}{22-01-2015} \\ 

\ganttgroup{Group1}                             {16-01-2015}{06-03-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewbar{Task2}                             {16-01-2015}{06-02-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewbar{Task3}                             {02-02-2015}{13-02-2015} \\
\ganttnewbar{Task4}                             {16-02-2015}{06-03-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewbar{Task5}                             {20-01-2015}{06-03-2015} \\ 

\ganttgroup{Group2}                             {23-03-2015}{10-04-2015}\\
\ganttnewbar{Task6}                             {23-03-2015}{10-04-2015} \\   

\ganttgroup {Group3}                            {02-03-2015}{20-03-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewbar{Task7}                             {02-03-2015}{20-03-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewYL {Task8}                             {23-03-2015}{10-04-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewYL {Task9}                             {02-03-2015}{06-03-2015} \\ 
\ganttnewYL{Task10}                             {09-03-2015}{10-04-2015} \\

\ganttnewbar{Task11}                            {13-04-2015}{24-04-2015} \\

\ganttnewbar{Task12}                            {27-04-2015}{14-05-2015} \\

\ganttnewbar{Task13}                            {12-01-2015}{14-05-2015} \\

\ganttmilestone{Milestone}                      {14-05-2015} \\

\ganttlink{elem10}{elem11}
\ganttlink{elem11}{elem14}

\ganttlink{elem16}{elem17}
\end{ganttchart}
}

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: Output from provided code]

To clarify, I expected the previously mentioned lines to put the labels above the bars, please could you tell me why they are not and advise on how to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It turns out that I was putting the command in the wrong place.
By moving the `bar inline label node /.style=north` into the `\begin{ganttchart}[options]` as follows:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[canvas/.style=%
                {pattern=weekendstripes, pattern color=gray!20},
                x unit= 2.9mm,
                y unit chart= 8mm,
                vgrid={*{6}{dotted},*{1}{black}},
                hgrid, 
                inline,
                time slot format=little-endian,
                newbar inline label node/.style={above=3pt}, %This line !!
                newYL inline label node/.style={above=3pt},  %and this one
                group/.append style={draw=black, fill=RoyalBlue!70},
                milestone/.append style={draw=black, fill=RoyalBlue!70},
                milestone inline label node/.append style={left=5mm}            
              ] {12-01-2015}{14-05-2015}
```

newbar and newYL (badly named I know) correspond to the user set bar styles as shown in the original question.